# By signal activating, an output should go to 1 and reset to 0 after 4 minutes, but it doesn't. Why not?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation

When an alarm signal is activated, the output should go 1 for 4 minutes and then reset to 0.  Every `posedge` of `clk_out` comes after 1 second.

```
module alarm4(input clk,alarm, output reg clk_out,output reg out);
    reg[7:0]alrm_counter=8'd0;
    reg[15:0]counter=16'd0;
    parameter DIVISOR = 16'd32768;

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
    counter<=counter+16'd1;
    if(counter>=(DIVISOR-1))
    begin
    counter<=16'd0;
    end
    clk_out<=(counter<DIVISOR/2)?1'b1:1'b0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk_out)
    begin
    if(alarm)
       begin 
         out<=1'b1;
         alrm_counter <= alrm_counter + 1'd1;
         if(alrm_counter == 8'b11110000)
            alrm_counter <= 1'd0;
       end
    end
    endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module tb();
reg clk;
reg alarm;
wire clk_out;
wire out;
alarm4 uut(clk,alarm,clk_out,out);

initial begin
clk = 0;
forever #15050 clk=~clk;
end

initial
begin
alarm = 1'b0;
#15050
alarm =1'b1;
#98364
alarm =1'b0;
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

[image: simulation 1]

[image: simulation 2]

Answer (score 1):

Your code sets the `out` output signal in the `alarm4` module to 1, but that is the only assignment to that signal.  Your code never makes another assignment to it.  Once it is set to 1, it can never change it's value.

You need to add another assignment to `out`.  For example,

```
always @(posedge clk_out)
begin
if(alarm)
   begin 
     out<=1'b1;
     alrm_counter <= alrm_counter + 1'd1;
     if(alrm_counter == 8'b11110000)
        alrm_counter <= 1'd0;
   end
else 
   begin
      // if (something) out <= 0;
   end
end
```

You need to decide what `something` is in the commented code above.

Comment: I like the change to 8 bit binary format. Makes events more implicit.